# How can I get rid of hallucination side effects?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-3

After an hallucination, the screen just fades to black and comes back repeatedly for a few moments, and then it comes back to normal. Can I get rid of those hallucination side effects faster, or am I stuck to play with those side effects until they clear out?

Comment: I don't know if I'm correct about this but I think you just have to reboot the ventilation because they break it when they come into your room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reboot the ventilation system.  Other than that, the effects go away after you reboot it.